# Testing a swift script by importing another script class

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a script that I need to test. Is there a way to test swift scripts by importing another script's class?

For example this is my script:

ScriptA.swift

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

class Main {
    func convertNameIntoLowerCase(_ name: String) -> String {
      return name.lowercased()
  }
}
```

For the tests I want to be able to import ScriptA.swift and test its functions

ScriptATests.swift

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation
import XCTest


class ATest : XCTestCase {
   func testIt() {
     XCTAssertTrue("sarah", Main.convertNameIntoLowerCase("SARAH"))
   }
}
```

Comment: Look into using the [Package Manager](https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager)

Comment: Add the file to the test target (check the checkbox in Target Membership)

Comment: @vadian these are stand alone scripts, they don't belong to a project